# Problem : setTimeOut with Animated.timing().start

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I am facing an issue with Animation (Animated) in react-native.

```
setTimeout(() => { AnimationToStart(onClose)); }, 1000);
```

The animation is working perfectly fine when I am not using setTimeOut but when using it and reaching the 1000ms only onClose is executed but the animation doesn't.

Below is my hook where I get my `AnimationToStart` from

```
    const useAnimation = ({
  values = { initialValue: 0, finalValue: 1 },
  stylesToAnimate = {
    styleOpacity: { start: 0, end: 1 },
    styleTop: { start: 60, end: 0 },
  },
  duration = 300,
  easing = Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
}: IHook) => {
  const { initialValue, finalValue } = values;
  const { styleOpacity, styleTop } = stylesToAnimate;

  const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialValue)).current;

  const top = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [initialValue, finalValue],
    outputRange: [styleTop.start, styleTop.end],
  });

  const opacity = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [initialValue, finalValue],
    outputRange: [styleOpacity.start, styleOpacity.end],
  });

  const AnimationToEnd = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: finalValue,
      duration,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      easing,
    }).start();
  };

  const AnimationToStart = (end = () => {}, delay = 0) => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: initialValue,
      duration,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      delay,
    }).start(() => end());
  };

  const animatedStyles = { top, opacity };

  return { animatedStyles, AnimationToStart, AnimationToEnd };
};
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

setTimout() won't work with Animated

Instead use the delay attribute, and set delay to 1000 (ms) instead of using setTimeout

```
 Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: initialValue,
      duration,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      delay: 1000,
    }).start(() => end());
```

Answer (score -2):

setTimeout() has syntax:

```
setTimeout(Function, Time in miliseconds);
```

For Example:

```
setTimeout(function example(){console.log("example")}, 1000);
```